# Drawing using PyQt Painter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using PyQt5 and I want to draw a text based on user's click on an existing pushbutton.

the text appears directly on Qwidget, I want the text to appear just after clicking the button.
how to do it?

my code is like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *



class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.text = "Just For Test"

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Drawing text')
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        self.btn1.move(10, 10)
        self.show()
    def paintEvent(self,event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawText(event, qp)
        qp.end()



    def drawText(self, event, qp):
        qp.setPen(QColor(168, 34, 3))
        qp.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 10))
        qp.drawText(event.rect(), Qt.AlignCenter, self.text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set text to empty one:

```
self.text = ""
```

Then, it's important to create a button click event:

```
self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.button_click)
```

Create a function to be called by clicking the button:

```
def button_click(self):
    self.text = "Just For Test"
    self.repaint()
```

Repaint will refresh your `QPaint`